# 301 dynamic redirect with parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx, http-status-code-301

How would 301 redirect with url parameters (dynamic) would look like in both htaccess and nginx?

Example:

`301 http://supercoolsite.com?you=awesome to http://evencooler.com?you=awesome`

`301 http://supercoolsite.com/somecategory?you=awesome to http://evencooler.com/category/subcategory?you=awesome`

Redirect needs to be dynamic. This means that it doesn't depend on url. It just needs to append same url parameters from url to destination url.

Comment: But your original URL has `/category` which is missing in target URL. Is that how you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^supercoolsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://evencooler.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

http://supercoolsite.com?you=awesome to http://evencooler.com?you=awesome